# C# Add extra property/info to a Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I want to add a extra property or info to a image. 
I tried using a new class that gets the image propertys and i just add one, but i have no idea how to do this.

Also i cant use the property "Tag" thats already in use, and cant be overwritten

```
public partial class myImage : System.Windows.Controls.Image
{
        //? 
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a dependency property, or do you actually don't know how to write a property in a C# class declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a property to a class derived from Image would look like this:

```
public class MyImage : Image
{
    public string AdditionalInfoProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You could also create a Property that would hold an `ImageSource` object:

```
public class MyImage
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfoProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your xaml you would use it like this, assuming that the `DataContext` holds an object of type `MyImage`.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AdditionalInfoProperty}"/>
```

Comment: `System.Windows.Controls.Image` can't be assigned to the `Image.Source` property. It should be ImageSource, and you should explain the difference. And please tell what exactly you think INPC is (and probably what's its use when you only have auto-implemented properties).

Comment: You're right @Clemens, I got a bit lazy. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Whoa! Easy there. Main point of the answer is to show the way of implementing the properties and how to use them as a solution. I accept that the information is not 100% correct, but there is no need for harsh words.

Comment: Sure, but it could so easily be made right. I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Gets or sets a value that represents the author of an image.

```
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> Author { get; set; }
```

The following code example shows how to write metadata to a bitmap image by using friendly properties of the BitmapMetadata class.

```
FileStream stream3 = new FileStream( "image2.tif", FileMode.Create );
BitmapMetadata myBitmapMetadata = new BitmapMetadata( "tiff" );
TiffBitmapEncoder encoder3 = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
myBitmapMetadata.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Digital Image Suite 10";
myBitmapMetadata.Author = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>( 
    new List<string>() { "Mehdi Daustany" } );
myBitmapMetadata.CameraManufacturer = "Tailspin Toys";
myBitmapMetadata.CameraModel = "TT23";
myBitmapMetadata.Comment = "Nice Picture";
myBitmapMetadata.Copyright = "2010";
myBitmapMetadata.DateTaken = "5/23/2010";
myBitmapMetadata.Keywords = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>( 
    new List<string>() { "Mehdi", "Daustany" } );
myBitmapMetadata.Rating = 5;
myBitmapMetadata.Subject = "Mehdi";
myBitmapMetadata.Title = "Mehdi's photo";

// Create a new frame that is identical to the one 
// from the original image, except for the new metadata. 
encoder3.Frames.Add( 
    BitmapFrame.Create( 
    decoder2.Frames[0], 
    decoder2.Frames[0].Thumbnail, 
    myBitmapMetadata, 
    decoder2.Frames[0].ColorContexts ) );

encoder3.Save( stream3 );
stream3.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

consider you have an image

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("C:\\temp\\smth\\smth.jpg");
```

use system drawing to get propertyitem

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem prop = img.PropertyItems[0];
```

set info

```
SetProperty(ref prop, 33432, "Test Info...");
img.SetPropertyItem(prop);
```

Comment: The question is about WPF.

Comment: So i am using a database and i want to add an int (Person_ID) to the image so i can dircetly see which image belongs to which person without using the database again

Comment: when you save your file you can add Id to the path of the file it is one way then u can use SetProperty attr to add id one of the property item